# How to count occurrences of dictionary key and sum values and print them?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am going to calculate bandwidth accessed by domain and need to know how many times domain got hit. I was able to calculate bandwidth but not sure how to count occurrence of domain in logs. Any idea would be great help. Thank you so much for help in advance.

Code:

```
import os
import re
from collections import defaultdict  
import string

merged_logs = []
line=[]
dict = defaultdict(int)
bandwidth = 0

path = ["/var/logs/"]

for i in path:
   for filename in os.listdir(i):
       with open(os.path.join(i, filename), 'r') as filedata:
           merged_logs += filedata.readlines()


for line in merged_logs:
  line_split = line.split(" ")
  start = "CONNECT "
  end = " -"
  domain_str = line[line.find(start)+len(start):line.find(end)]
if domain_str.find("/")>0:
   domain_split = domain_str.split("/")
   domain = domain_split[0]
   if len(line_split)==10:

     bandwidth = line_split[3]

   if len(line_split)==11:

      bandwidth = line_split[4]
   else:
     domain = domain_str

  if len(line_split)==10:
     bandwidth = line_split[3]

  if len(line_split)==11:

     bandwidth = line_split[4]

if domain not in dict:
   dict[domain] = int(bandwidth)
else:
   dict[domain] += int(bandwidth)

for key, value in dict.items():
    print key, (value * 2 )/(1024 * 1024)
```

Example Log file under /var/logs contains following lines:

```
1569935790.563 1010 192.168.10.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1001803 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/www.google.com - 192.168.100.3
1569935790.563 1010 192.168.10.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1001085 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/www.google.com - 192.168.100.3
1569935790.563 1010 192.168.10.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1000182 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/www.google.com - 192.168.100.3
1569935790.563 1010 192.168.10.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1006183 CONNECT www.xyz.com/index.php - HIER_DIRECT/www.xyz.com - 192.168.100.3
1569935790.563 1010 192.168.10.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1091083 CONNECT www.xyz.com/index.php - HIER_DIRECT/www.xyz.com - 192.168.100.3
1569935790.563 1010 192.168.10.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 2091803 CONNECT www.xyz.com/index.php - HIER_DIRECT/www.xyz.com - 192.168.100.3
1569935790.563 1010 192.168.10.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 2091083 CONNECT www.xyz.com/index.php - HIER_DIRECT/www.xyz.com - 192.168.100.3
59375 192.168.10.3 TAG_NONE/503 10 CONNECT www.google.com - HIER_NONE/- - 192.168.100.3
```

Output should be in the format:

```
Domain        Bandwidth (MB)     Hit (Count)

www.xyz.com        11                  4
www.google.com      5                  3
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your `dict` structure? (`dict` is a poor variable name as it overwrites a builtin function, BTW)

Comment: @ggorlen, I have shared codes. Can you please look into it? Thank you.

Comment: @ggorlen, I have shared sample log lines. Can you please check it? Thank you.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is the `1001803` column the bandwidth? Looks like you're summing this for each domain and then doing `(sum * 2) / (1024 * 1024)`, but why are you testing that it might be in a different column--is this a fully representative sample of the data format, or will columns be missing, etc?

Comment: @ggorlen, Yes, you are right, that column is bandwidth in bytes and I need it multiplied by 2 for both upload and download. Also data is required in MB so divided 1024 two times. Column will not be missing but length of column varies from 10 to 11, so , I am checking it and selecting correct column which you can see in the code. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm--all columns appear to be 11 in the provided example. Can you show what one of the 10 columns looks like?

Comment: @ggorlen, I have added a sample line having 10 column in log line. Can you please check it? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, that makes a huge difference. Thanks for clarifying. Please add any other lines that have any differences. For example, can I assume the URL will always be whatever column follows `CONNECT` and that `CONNECT` is always present? The reason I'm asking all these questions is because I want to create a solution that will actually work for you, and the spec is unclear to me so far. Also, please update your output to reflect the new line you added (it's underreporting google now). Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import re
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import string

# Compile Regex pattern beforehand for optimized computation
domain_pattern = re.compile("(CONNECT )(?P<domain>.*?)( -)")
# Initialize a defaultdict for Storing and Updating the Sum of Bandwidths
bandwidths = defaultdict(int)
# Initialize a Counter for Storing and Updating the Count of Hits
counts = Counter()

path = ["/var/logs/"]

for i in path:
    for filename in os.listdir(i):
        with open(os.path.join(i, filename), 'r') as filedata:
            merged_logs += filedata.readlines()

for line in merged_logs:
    line_split = line.split(" ")
    # Use re.search function to get the string matching the Regex Pattern
    # Use group method to just fetch the named group: 'domain' as specified in the pattern
    domain_str = re.search(domain_pattern, line).group('domain')
    domain = domain_str.split("/")[0]

    if len(line_split) == 10:
        bandwidth = line_split[3]

    elif len(line_split) == 11:
        bandwidth = line_split[4]

    else:
        pass

    # Update the defaultdict to add the bandwidth
    bandwidths[domain] += int(bandwidth)
    # Update the Counter to increment the count by 1
    counts[domain] += 1

for domain in bandwidths:
    bandwidth = int((bandwidths[domain] * 2 ) / (1024 * 1024))
    hits = counts[domain]
    print domain, bandwidth, hits
```

I ran the above code on the sample logs, to get the following output:

```
www.google.com:443  5       3
www.xyz.com         11      4
www.google.com      0       1
```

Comment: @ Animesh Mishra, Thank you so much for your code and solving my problem.